# wrong time on android device using cordova but correct time in browser

Tags: javascript, android, datetime

So my issue is when using javascript new Date() on my android device (cordova app) it returns the wrong time:

using cordova globalisation - correct time

> Wed Apr 20 2016 11:38:00 GMT-0200 (_TZif)

javascript new Date() - wrong time

> Wed Apr 20 2016 04:08:44 GMT-0200 (_TZif)

new Date().toUTCString() - wrong time -1 hour

> Wed, 20 Apr 2016 06:08:44 GMT

moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') - wrong time

> April 20th 2016, 4:08:44 am

My device is set to the local time zone where i am and so is my PC - india standard time.

If i use the cordova plugin for the correct time and save the value using getTime()

> 1461159480044

Then in my browser the time is:

> Wed Apr 20 2016 19:08:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Either way if i use the correct time in the app the wrong time displays on the website. Using the wrong time in the app shows the correct time in the web site.

Obviously the timezone is wrong in the android app but how can i get it to be correct? The timezone is manually set to Indian standard time. So is my PC when building it. My laptop and mobile are from UK but i've changed the date timezone settings manually. My localhost displays the correct time on the laptop.

What to do?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't change timezone devices when in another country, just change the time on the device itself.

Comment: Is this on a samsung device?

Comment: This is not an answer. Many users want to change the timezone

Answer (score -1):

Change the timezone on devices back to original (UK standard time) and set the time difference on the device.

Values are now:

> new Date('cordova globalisation function').getTime(): 1461150716400

cordova globalisation:  Wed Apr 20 2016 12:11:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

> new Date():  Wed Apr 20 2016 12:11:56 GMT+0100 (BST)

new Date().toUTCString():  Wed, 20 Apr 2016 11:11:56 GMT

> moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'):  April 20th 2016, 12:11:56 pm